# need two return value from a stored procedure in c#

Tags: sql

I want to call a Stored Procedure which takes two parameters(username & password) and returns two values of type int( 'result' and 'group' ) 'result' for checking whether the user is valid or not and 'group' simply shows the group number of customers
there are three type of groups
group#1 : admin users
group#2 : custom users 
grpup#3 : special users

below is my current code which only returns result

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[suserpass] 
@username Varchar(50), 
@password varchar(50), 
@result int OUTPUT,
@group int OUTPUT

AS
IF EXISTS (select [user]   from [userpassTable] where [user] = @username and [pass]=@password) 
  set @result=1  

else 
  set @result=0
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need do soemthing as below you need to set both output variable that will do your task .....

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[suserpass] 
    @username Varchar(50), 
    @password varchar(50), 
    @result int OUTPUT,
    @group int OUTPUT

    AS
    IF EXISTS (select [user]   from [userpassTable] where [user] = @username and [pass]=@password) 
    begin
      select @result=1
      select @group = usergroup from [userpassTable] where [user] = @username and [pass]=@password  
    end 
    else
    begin 
      select @result=0
      select @group=0
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set both output parameters.

You can do it like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT [user] FROM [userpassTable] 
           WHERE [user] = @username AND [pass] = @password) 
BEGIN
  SELECT @result=1 , @group = group
  FROM [userpassTable] 
  WHERE [user] = @username
END
else 
BEGIN
  SELECT @result=0 , @group = 0 -- group 0 doesn't exist, used as user does exist
END
```

I have added `BEGIN/END` blocks for readability and to allow more than one statement.

In your C# both `@result` and `@group` should be set to output parameters.

Comment: how will he use those values ? it has to go throught #t.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I don't follow. What is `#t`?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Why should a temporary table be needed?

Comment: How  would you use the value returned? can you give me simple query ?

Comment: AFAIK you cant use the result from SP as a query-able source. only through TMP table.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Since one is setting the `OUTPUT` parameters, these will be set and usable on the .NET side.

Comment: I know this one. Im talking pure SQL. ( didnt see hes miXing C#)

Comment: Which object–relational mapping technology are you using? LINQ-to-SQL supports stored procedures.

Comment: @Douglas - Who are you asking exactly?

Comment: I confused Royi Namir with the question poster. However, this information should have been provided as part of the question, given that it is tagged as C#.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that, conceptually, you’re looking for something like this (haven’t tested the code):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[suserpass] 
@username Varchar(50), 
@password varchar(50), 
@result int OUTPUT,
@group int OUTPUT

AS
IF EXISTS (select [user] from [userpassTable] where [user] = @username and [pass] = @password) 
  BEGIN
    set @result = 1
    set @group = (select (top 1) [groupType] from [userGroupTable] where [user] = @username)
  END
else     
  set @result=0
```